# Getting Exception within reading dates in java

Tags: java, date, exception

I'm solving a problem that, given the initial date and the final date, returns the number of days between them.

I just finished and my answer seems to be correct, but it says that at some input, my method of reading the year fails and it throws an exception.

Here is my code of reading dates and parsing them to integers:

```
    String si = in.nextLine();
    String sf = in.nextLine();

    int di = Integer.parseInt(si.substring(0, 2)); 
    int mi = Integer.parseInt(si.substring(3, 5));
    int ai = Integer.parseInt(si.substring(6, si.length()));

    int df = Integer.parseInt(sf.substring(0, 2)); 
    int mf = Integer.parseInt(sf.substring(3, 5));
    int af = Integer.parseInt(sf.substring(6, sf.length()));
```

The dates are given in format XX/XX/XXXX (just for security, I read the year using s.length to cover cases of year being <1000 or >9999)

What in this code can throw an exception at reading years at that format?

Comment: [`Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) can throw an `Exception`, as well as [`in.nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--)

Comment: As well as si.substring() or sf.substring() for any line that has less than 7 characters.

Comment: can you please explain the cases where it is happening??

Comment: I don't know, thats why I asked... I just send my code, but have no access to the input test. but i solved the problem looking for the numbers before, between and after the char '/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code snippet will work nicely:

```
    try {

        System.out.println("Entered Dates::\n");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String si = in.nextLine();

        if (Pattern.matches("\\d\\d/\\d\\d/\\d\\d\\d\\d", si)) {
            int di = Integer.parseInt(si.substring(0, 2));
            int mi = Integer.parseInt(si.substring(3, 5));
            int ai = Integer.parseInt(si.substring(6, si.length()));
            System.out.println("1st Date Accepted : " + di + "-" + mi + "-" + ai);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Entered 1st Date incorrect");
        }

        String sf = in.nextLine();
        if (Pattern.matches("\\d\\d/\\d\\d/\\d\\d\\d\\d", sf)) {
            int df = Integer.parseInt(sf.substring(0, 2));
            int mf = Integer.parseInt(sf.substring(3, 5));
            int af = Integer.parseInt(sf.substring(6, sf.length()));
            System.out.println("2nd Date Accepted : " + df + "-" + mf + "-" + af);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Entered 2nd Date incorrect");
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception occurred: " + e);
    }
```

Comment: "\\d\\d/\\d\\d/\\d\\d\\d\\d" is pattern in which you will access date from command line.
refer..http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html